# React Native setAllowFontScaling argument 1 has type boolean, got java.lang.Integer

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a heavy react native application where I am occasionally getting this error. The application has lots of images and texts but I am really unable to figure out the root cause of this issue

```
LOCATION    ViewManagersPropertyCache.java line 100 in com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp()
EXCEPTION   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
MESSAGE method com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextShadowNode.setAllowFontScaling argument 1 has type boolean, got java.lang.Integer
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please Use like following

```
import {Text} from 'react-native';

Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = true;
```

or

```
 <Text allowFontScaling={true}> Some Test Line </Text>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to grep your project to search the [`allowFontScaling`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.44/docs/text.html#allowfontscaling) prop. It should be a boolean but if you set it to an integer that's why you are seeing this error.

```
grep -rn "allowFontScaling" .
```